# Proving a lemma about the union of sets, linear independence, spans

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

OK, here’s another lemma I’m being asked to prove and I am trying to see if I am in the right ballpark.

Let $L = \{y, y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots, y_m\}$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$, a vector space over field $K$.

Let $S = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_r\}$ be a subset of $V$ such that $\{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m, x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_r\} = \big(L \backslash \{y\}\big) \cup\ S$ spans $V$.

Show that $\exists$ an element $x_i\in\ S$ s.t. $L \cup (S \backslash \{x_i\}) = \{y, y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m, x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x_i, x_{i+1}, x_n\}$ spans $V$.

I approached it like this:

Given that $\big(L \backslash \{y\}\big) \cup S$ spans $V$, that means that $y$ is linearly dependent, and thus a linear combination of $L \cup\ S$, so it can be expressed as:
$$y = \lambda_1y_1 + \lambda_2y_2 +\ldots + \lambda_m y_m + \mu_1x_1 + \mu_2x_2+ \ldots + \mu_rx_r.$$

By construction, $L$ is a linearly independent set, so $\exists$ scalars $c$ such that $cy + c_1y_1 + c_2y_2 + \ldots + c_my_m = 0 $.

But since we have $L$ as linearly independent, that means the coefficients have to be zero. That’s true for both $L$ as a linearly independent set with scalar coefficient $c$ and $\lambda_i$.

That in turn reduces $y = \lambda_1y_1 + \lambda_2y_2 + \ldots + \lambda_m y_m + \mu_1x_1 + \mu_2x_2+ \ldots + \mu_rx_r$ to $y = \mu_1x_1 + \mu_2x_2+ \ldots + \mu_rx_r$.

But $y$ isn’t linearly independent. That means at least one of the coefficients $\mu_i \neq 0$, therefore there is some element $x_i \neq 0$.

The span of $V$ is the set of all vectors in $V$. And we’re trying to show that the union of $L$ and $S$ with that nonzero $x_i$ subtracted is the span of $V$. But that’s where I get a little stuck; I know I’ve almost got the last step.

(Also, any critique on how to write this proof “properly” is much appreciated.)

Comment: In the right ballpark... lol :)

Comment: "by construction L is a linearly independent set, $\exists$ scalars c such that "
That's the opposite. By linear independence, the only possibilities for $c, c_1, \dots, c_m$ is $c = c_1 = \dots = c_m = 0$. I know that's what you wrote, but you're kind of saying stuff for nothing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't know that $\{ y, x_1, \dots, x_r \}$ is a linearly dependent subset! You are misunderstanding the definitions. The problem is that when you write 
$$
y = \lambda_1 y_1 + \dots + \lambda_m y_m + \mu_1 x_1 + \dots + \mu_r x_r,
$$
you cannot assume that all coefficients $\lambda$ will be zero. Think of $V = \mathbb R^2$ with basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$, $L = \{ e_1, e_2 \}$ and $S = \{e_1 + e_2\}$ and see what happens with your equations.

The right proof would go like this : since $\{ y_1,\dots,y_m , x_1, \dots, x_r\}$ spans $V$, we have 
$$
y = \lambda_1 y_1 + \dots + \lambda_m y_m + \mu_1 x_1 + \dots + \mu_r x_r,
$$
and we cannot have all $\mu_i$'s equal to zero, because this would give a linear dependence on the set $\{y,y_1,\dots, y_m\}$. Therefore one of the $\mu$'s is not zero. Say $\mu_i \neq 0$. Then 
$$
x_i = \frac {-1}{\mu_i}\left( \lambda_1 y_1 + \dots + \lambda_m y_m + \mu_1 x_1 + \dots + 0 x_i + \dots + \mu_r x_r - y \right),
$$
which means even though the set $\{y,y_1, \dots, y_m, x_1, \dots, x_r \}$ spans $V$, the element $x_i$ is not necessary to span $V$, so we can remove it from this set and still have a generating set for $V$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: That does help. Just so I understand tho, the hint my prof gave was that since (L-{y}) $\cup$ S spans V, y is a linear combination of $y_1, ...,y_m, x_1, ...,x_r$. And that we should use the linear independence of L to conclude there is at least one $x_i$ that is nonzero. Anyhow, I assumed y was linearly dependent because it could be written as a linear combination. And that a linearly independent set would have coefficients that go to zero. Which part was a wrong understanding?